# RibbonX - using comboBox to run macro / VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, ribbonx, custom-ui

I am new to custom menus but have been successful at using Ribbon X to set up some custom tabs / groups in Excel. They are ribbon buttons that run macros (fairly basic stuff like hiding columns).

What I really want to do is to have a ribbon comboBox (or dropdown) which can be used to filter a table on specific columns. I have some macros which work - a simple example is filtering on a column called PRIORITY. I have a macro called "P1" which filters the table to show Priority 1 items "P2" for Priority 2 items etc. If I run these macros manually they have the desired effect.

Next step is how to get them to run from the menu.

I have tried this:

```
<group id="customGroup3" label="Content Filters">
    <comboBox id="comboBox1" label="Priority Filter">
        <item id="item2" label="P1" onAction="P1"/>
        <item id="item3" label="P2" onAction="P2"/>
    </comboBox>
</group>
```

This doesn't work because I get a validation error "The 'onAction' attribute is not declared.". I think I have read that you can't have "onAction" as an attrbute of a comboBox item.

What do I need to do to get macro P1 to run if P1 is selected in the comboBox and macro P2 if P2 is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onAction` attribute for the item element in the Ribbon UI. Possible attributes are `id`, `image`, `imageMso`, `label`, `screentip`, `supertip`.

It seems you are interested in the `onChange` callback of the `combobox` control which has the following signature:

```
C#: void OnChange(IRibbonControl control, string text)

VBA: Sub OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String)

C++: HRESULT OnChange([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [in] BSTR *pbstrText)

Visual Basic: Sub OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String)
```

Read more about possible controls and their attributes in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)